# Can't compare stringA > stringB

Tags: c#, string, compare

I am trying to do somthing like this:

```
  // some code...

  string a="aa";
  string b="bb";
  // ...
  if(b>a)    // suppose to be true
   {
     // do somthing
   }
```

But then I get the compile error:

> Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and
>   'string'.

So what is the best approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use *[`CompareTo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compare.aspx)* method instead of.

```
if(b.CompareTo(a) > 0)
```

> Compares two specified String objects and returns an integer that
>   indicates their relative position in the sort order.

This method ;

> - if b is greater than a or a is null, it returns greater than zero.
> - if b is less than a, it returns less than zero.
> - if b has the same position in the sort order as a, it returns 0.

Check this *[`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/MesLbH)*.

Comment: Note that this does a comparison that depends on the current `CultureInfo` of the current thread. In most cultures, for example, `"é"` is less than `"f"` because "a kind of e" comes before an f in that culture. If instead you want to compare by the numerical values of the `char` values in the strings, use `CompareOrdinal` instead. Here `"é"` will be greater than `"f"` if `"é"` is normalized as one `char`, namely U+00E9. But `"é"` might also be normalized as U+0065 followed by U+0301, and the `"é"` is less than `"f"` in ordinal comparison.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yep, this method depends on current `CultureInfo`, even in my country (Turkey) there could be [much more problem](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/whats-wrong-with-turkey.html).

Comment: Turkish (`"tr-TR"`) is a nice culture! My culture is `"da-DK"`, and it also offers some surprises. For example `"Great"` will be _less_ than `"Gönül"` in the culture `"da-DK"`. The reason is that `"Gönül"` is to be consider a variant of `"Gønyl"` (sorry, it's Danish!), and the letter `ø` comes near the end of the Danish alphabet (and after `r`), not close to `o` like in Turkish.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen `Gønyl`? Really? Love it :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yep you are right. It throws null reference exceptions. Do you have a suggestion for preventing it?

Comment: Sure: `string.Compare(a, b)` of manually checking for `null` of course. :)

Comment: @SonerGönül more than anything else, small i and capital I annoys a lot rather than anything else. (Different handling in .NET, different in databases, i remember the database connection string). The flip side is, if one passes turkey test, he/she can be rest assured it will run in all (left to right) languages.

Comment: @Tilak Yeah unfortunately, that's why maybe turkey past is more important than we think.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(string.Compare(a, b) > 0)
```

You can use `==` & `!=` but not the other operators, use [string.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/84787k22.aspx) instead

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CompareTo`.

```
if (b.CompareTo(a) > 0) { /*Operate*/ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings cannot be compared like that, you should use String.Compare() as shown in this article on MSDN [How to: Compare Strings (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165449.aspx)

Comment: External links on their own dont make for a great answer, as they are third party controlled and the links might not always be active. Summarise the useful parts of that link in an answer however, and its usefulness increases tenfold

Comment: @RhysW I agree, but still we are talking about the primary source where basic programming skills can be learned from -> MSDN. And albeit the link might not exist in a few years, then the answer might not be relevant anymore because newer methods might arise that will be the recommended practice.

Comment: if the hosting server is down for the external links this answer would be totally useless on its own as it stands. Im not talking about irrelevancce in a few years or whether or not it is a good source.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CompareTo`:

```
if(b.CompareTo(a) > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at [String class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) you'll see that operators `>` or `<` are not defined for this type but `ComapreTo` method is and that's the way to go - as stated in other answers.

If you want to use these operators on a string type, you have to implement a custom string type and overload these relational operators for it. That class could look like this:

```
    public class MyString
    {
        string str;

        public MyString(string str)
        {
            this.str = str;
        }

        public static implicit operator MyString(string str)
        {
            return new MyString(str);
        }

        public static bool operator < (MyString str1,  MyString str2)
        {
            return (str1.str.CompareTo(str2.str) < 0);
        }

        public static bool operator >(MyString str1, MyString str2)
        {
            return (str1.str.CompareTo(str2.str) > 0);
        }

        public static bool operator ==(MyString str1, MyString str2)
        {
            return (str1.str.CompareTo(str2.str) == 0);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(MyString str1, MyString str2)
        {
            return (str1.str.CompareTo(str2.str) != 0);
        }

        // other methods and overloads
    }


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyString str1 = "abba";
        MyString str2 = "abbb";
        MyString str3 = "abba";
        MyString str4 = "aabb";

        Debug.Assert(str1 < str2);
        Debug.Assert(str1 == str3);
        Debug.Assert(str1 > str4);            
    }
 }
```